# Amazon EC2 from Windows Server 2008 backup

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2

Can I restore a windows 2008 backup to and from Amazon EC2?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you can:

1. Start a standard Windows AMI
2. Stop it.
3. Create an EBS Volume big enough to hold the backup
4. Dump the backup to that volume
5. Swap the root volume of the Windows instance you started with that volume.
6. Start the instance.

I suspect that will actually get your instance up and running. It's a weird workaround of their licensing limitations.

Comment: This is exactly how I handle backup and restore for my Windows instances on EC2 - so I can confirm this works. If you meant a backup of Windows from outside EC2 though, I'd really, really doubt it.